# Filling a List from an external source

Tags: python, sql, arrays, list

I’ve got my basic procedural code going and wish to add my next element, which involves accessing an array from an external data source to feed my For loop.

Let’s say I have the following static array in my procedure, which I understand is called a list in Python. It that correct?

```
myLists = ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Orange']

for myList in myLists:

    Do something etc
```

I wish to modify this so that I can fill it with a dynamic range of elements from an external source (but located on the local machine).

E.g, Can I fill the array with a list from a SQL DB query? Or can I fill it from a txt file list?

So, my SQL DB hosts the elements I wish iterate through in my Python script.

1. Can I link and fill this directly from my SQL DB? How? Or
2. Should I export the elements from SQL DB to a txt file and read that? If so, how do I fill my array with a list of elements from a txt file? Or
3. Maybe another approach I haven’t considered

I think the first option is the most direct but overall I have no idea how to approach this task.

Comment: Look at the `MySQLdb` library for an sql interface

Comment: Thanks Muddyfish, will investigate MySQLdb lib. Just to clarify my DB is SQL Server rather than MySQL.

Comment: Then look at a different library for interfacing with the server you are using.

Comment: ok - I found pymssql libraryand been working on this. I can now log into my SQL Server and Query. The only thing is the output isn't quite as I expect. When I print each row from my query results is adds a the (,) characters.                                                                                               Eg data
('WES',)
('WFD',)
('WHC',)                                                                                                        The source data would be WES of type string, so I am expecting 'WES' but not ('WES',). What's happening and what do I do about it?

Comment: I found " | ".join(row) this to fix my issue. Something to do with tuples...